# ruby on rails : How do use ORM from remote connect DB server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried and success Remote Conncect database(based ruby on rails).

Server with Original database based PostgreSQL and made from another ruby on rails web framework. and database has a 'hit_products' table(Model name: HitProduct)

after remote connect database, I did a Migrate.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

and when I access Rails Console, I input this code :

```
HitProduct.first(3)
```

I expect like under result :

```
ubuntu:~/environment (master) $ rails c
2020-01-19 07:34:25 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
Running via Spring preloader in process 8830
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
2.6.3 :001 > HitProduct.first(3)
  HitProduct Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "hit_products".* FROM "hit_products" ORDER BY "hit_products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 3]]
 => [#<HitProduct id: 1, title: "[STEAM] Merry Snowballs temporary free", created_at: "2020-01-18 03:53:22", updated_at: "2020-01-18 03:53:22">, #<HitProduct id: 2, title: "LG ultra HDTV 65UM781C3NA", created_at: "2020-01-18 03:53:22", updated_at: "2020-01-18 03:53:22">, #<HitProduct id: 3, title: "[Wemakeprice] 20 LG GRAM 17D90N-VX30K", created_at: "2020-01-18 03:53:22", updated_at: "2020-01-18 03:53:22">]
```

but the output is Like this :

```
ubuntu:~/environment (master) $ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 5594
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4.1)
2.4.0 :001 > HitProduct.first(3)
NameError: uninitialized constant HitProduct
        from (irb):1
```

but SQL Query is worked.

```
ubuntu:~/environment (master) $ rails db
Password: *******
Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

catch_dev=# SELECT title FROM hit_products LIMIT 3;
                           title
-----------------------------------------------------------
[STEAM] Merry Snowballs temporary free
LG ultra HDTV 65UM781C3NA
[Wemakeprice] 20 LG GRAM 17D90N-VX30K
(3 rows)

catch_dev=#
```

How Could I use ORM from another server(Use DB from remote server)?

Comment: Your issue seems to be you should declare your ActiveRecord models in both applications. Connecting database from another Rails app does not allow you to access Ruby classes magically. Declare HitProduct in app/models the same way you did it in the other application.

Comment: @Jean-MichelGigault Database remote access was allowed. but At that time, I didn't know how to use ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it!

1. make Model file : `app/models/hit_product.rb`
2. input under code

```
class HitProduct < ApplicationRecord
  # establish_connection "[DATABASE ENVIRONMENT]".to_sym
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}".to_sym

  # self.table_name = "[TABLE_NAME]"
  self.table_name = "hit_products"
end
```

3. It work!!